# How to get the cell position in JQXGrid

Tags: position, screen, jqxgrid

I want to get a cell position. I am having field's name and row index.
How to get the cell position (x, y) in the screen to place the JQXWindow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
`var cell = $('#jqxGrid').jqxGrid('getcellatposition', left, top);`
```

- The getcellatposition method can get you a cell by knowing the x and y. More Grid examples: [jQuery Grid Demos](https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxgrid/index.htm)